# why to use isnull(field,'') =2?

Tags: sql-server

I have a field to update which uses isnull(field,'') = 2. But I am getting error as the field has character value in it?

for exaample : field = 'E'
It says conversion failed converting varchar value 'E' to datatype int

Comment: Are you asking why you are getting the error message or is your question more to do with the ISNULL statement?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you are working with two different data types. `ISNULL(field,'')` implies that you are working with a character field.  `2` however is a number.  Which do you need?

You can do something like this:

```
ISNULL(field,'') = '2'
```

But if field happens to be `'02'` then the result will be false.

Or if field is actually a number then you could do something like this:

```
ISNULL(field,0) = 2
```

But if field is a string data type that you are using to hold numbers and you just happen to have an `'Q'` in the `field` then you are going to get a conversion error.

I'm assuming the first option is best since you are getting the error on `'E'`.

---

When you use the code you actually have it is doing an implicit conversion behind the scenes.  If you look at the XML execution plan for the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE #DataTypeTest (Col1 varchar(50))

INSERT INTO #DataTypeTest VALUES ('1'),('2')

SELECT *
FROM #DataTypeTest
WHERE ISNULL(Col1,'') = 2
```

You'll see this line (talking about the ISNULL)

```
 <ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,isnull([tempdb].[dbo].[#DataTypeTest].[Col1],''),0)=(2)">
```

You can see how it's actually converting the `ISNULL` in to an `INT` data type.  This is because you are comparing it to a integer.  It doesn't convert the `2` to a string because `INT` is higher than `VARCHAR` on the [data type precedence list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx).

Now when it tries to convert the `ISNULL` formula into an integer it of course fails when the column contains an `E`.

Comment: You should add that using ISNULL, even `WHERE ISNULL(field,'') = '2'` that won't throw error, is practically useless. `WHERE field = '2'` would be simpler and have the same effect.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Very true. I didn't think to include that. I was focused on the data type confusion.